# Testing methods including the context and etc

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

How to test method that accesses the app `context`, for example in order to get a string from resources.

Code:

```
public String getString(Context context) {
    String string = context.getResources().getString(R.id.string);
    return string;
}
```

Test code:

```
MyClass myClass;

Context context; // ???

@Before
public void setUp(){
     myClass = new MyClass();
}

@Test
public void convertToMessage() throws Exception  {
    String myString = "My string";
    String gettedString = myClass.getString(context);
    assertEquals(myString, gettedString);
}
```

What to do with the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
     myClass = new MyClass();
     context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
}
```

See also [the Android testing documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#AndroidJUnitRunner) and [the `InstrumentationRegistry` JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html).

Comment: It turns out that I should run the test on the device for testing?

Comment: @whalemare: Yes, I assumed that you were looking to perform instrumentation testing. There is no `Context` directly available to you for unit testing (i.e., testing outside of Android), though it is possible that Robolectric or similar mocking frameworks will meet your needs.

Comment: Ok. Thanks you for help!)